Is there a way to add geotiff to mapbox dynamically?
Is it possible to display a GeoTIFF file on a Mapbox map without setting up or using a third-party geo/tile server?
So far, I’m aware of the following options:

Display the GeoTIFF as an image with specified coordinates.
Use Mapbox Studio to upload the GeoTIFF as a tileset.

However, neither of these solutions works for me. I have 300 small GeoTIFF files that are routinely updated by a satellite image provider. I only need to display one GeoTIFF at a time, so I prefer not to manually upload them every time they are updated or set up a GeoServer.
Ideally, I want a solution similar to this OpenLayers example:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cog-forked-iv3km6?file=%2Fmain.js%3A32%2C22.
